# How to configure composer to use a specific pull request?

Tags: php, github, composer-php, pull-request, packagist

I am using another author's composer package in Packagist where the source code is hosted by GitHub.

On GitHub, I performed a pull request, made some changes, and committed the changes.

The original author has not yet merged my pull request, and I would prefer not to submit my version as a new package to Packagist.

How should I configure `composer.json` for my application to use my pull request?

Comment: Maybe Use The Fork, Luke

Comment: @Cid :) I see what you did there :) :)

Comment: @Cid  Yes, thank you, I think so.  So, instead of using `"require": {"mysoftware/thesoftware": "^1.4"}`, looks like I would just use `"require": {"mysoftware/thesoftware": "^1.4#3f38376d"}`, right?

Comment: @Cid  What did you do?  "The Fork"?  "Luke"?

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I accidentally directed my previous comment to Cid instead of you and it is too late to edit.  I assume your previous comment before you edited it is still valid.

Comment: Think STAR WARS...... Luke

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Ah, got it!  Evidently, I shouldn't/couldn't use `^1.4#3f38376d` but instead `dev-master#3f38376d`.  Seems to work but received an error about `3f38376d` being gone and failed to download from source,  but then it downloaded correctly from the dist.